# Dynamic comparison of values of n multiple Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dynamic, multiple-columns, multipleselection

Let's say a user can input the columns and values to compare for a DF, so we can have:

```py
column_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
value_list = [val1, val2, val3]
```

So to select the rows that satisfy where col1 >= val1 AND col2 >= val2 AND col3 >= val3 we would write:

```py
selection = (df['col1'] >= val1) & (df['col2'] >= val2) & (df['col3'] >= val3))
```

or it can be in the form:

```py
selection  = df.loc[(df['col1'] >= val1) & (df['col2'] >= val2) & (df['col3'] >= val3)]
```

The number of columns is not known in advance, so we can have *n* columns. We can try this approach:

```py
if n=1:
   selection = (df['col1'] >= val1))
elif n=2:
   selection = (df['col1'] >= val1) & (df['col2'] >= val2))
elif n=3:
   selection = (df['col1'] >= val1) & (df['col2'] >= val2) & (df['col3'] >= val3))
```

But this is neither scalable nor efficient. I tried by generating strings `df['col<>'] >= val<>)` with a for loop given the input lists but it didn't work for Pandas because of the `str` format.

What would be the best pythonic approach for this? To avoid having all the options with if and else statements.

Comment: there is different `>,<, =>, <=` ?

Comment: OP, can you please confirm whether or not you mean to be mixing different comparison operators?

Comment: I will  update it, for all of them it should be ">="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform a comparison with the same operator for all columns, create a Series with the values and columns ids and use it to perform an aligned comparison with the dataframe:

```
df[df.gt(pd.Series(value_list, index=column_list)).all(1)]
```

Example input:

```
>>> value_list
[3, 7, 11]
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0     0     1     2
1     3     4     5
2     6     7     8
3     9    10    11
4    12    13    14
```

output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
4    12    13    14
```

intermediates:

```
>>> pd.Series(value_list, index=column_list)
col1     3
col2     7
col3    11

>>> df.gt(pd.Series(value_list, index=column_list))
    col1   col2   col3
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2   True  False  False
3   True   True  False
4   True   True   True

>>> df.gt(pd.Series(value_list, index=column_list)).all(1)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
```

Comment: Special emphasis on ***with the same operator***. Nice solution if this is what OP ends up needing.

Comment: it's simple and it solved the question as all the operators were the same, thank you! [mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway)

Comment: @juanman note that since you want `>=` you should use `ge` instead of `gt`.

Answer (score 2):

With a `df` like this,

```py
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
   a  b  c
0  1  7  7
1  2  1  1
2  6  2  6
3  2  6  3
4  3  3  8
5  5  9  0
```

And values, columns, and *arbitrary* operators,

```py
In [2]: import operator

In [3]: values = [1, 2, 7]

In [4]: columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [5]: operators = [operator.gt, operator.ge, operator.le]  # >,  >=,  <=
```

Make a copy of `df` and iterate over the zipped items:

```py
In [6]: selection = df.copy()

In [7]: for col, op, val in zip(columns, operators, values):
   ...:     selection = selection[op(selection[col], val)]
   ...:

In [8]: selection
Out[8]:
   a  b  c
2  6  2  6
3  2  6  3
5  5  9  0
```

Of course, if you don't know ahead of time how many columns there are, then it seems as though you also likely don't know the *operators* ahead of time either, which sort of defeats the purpose. This would become *much* easier if you only had to use a single operator but it looks like that's not the case, judging by your examples.

If your original post does indeed have typos (should all comparisons be `>`, or all of them `>=`?) and you actually intend to perform a *single* comparison operation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69295887/6298712) from @mozway.

Comment: Thank you for the input [ddejohn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6298712/ddejohn), it allows to have other combination of operators

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possibility to handle an arbitrary long list of comparisons (I am posting separately as the approach is quite different):

```
column_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
value_list = [3, 7, 11]
operator_list = [pd.Series.gt, pd.Series.ge, pd.Series.gt]

op_dic = dict(zip(column_list, operator_list))
val_dic = dict(zip(column_list, value_list))

df[df.apply(lambda c: op_dic[c.name](c, val_dic[c.name])).all(1)]
```

**How it works:**

Using `apply`, we perform a custom operation on all columns that will return a boolean per row, then take the rows that are True for all.

input:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     0     1     2
1     3     4     5
2     6     7     8
3     9    10    11
4    12    13    14
```

output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
4    12    13    14
```

*NB. to be more concise one can also do:*

```
from operator import gt, ge
operator_list = [gt, ge, gt]
```